# Syntax error on defining and using 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, syntax-error

```
public class PennyPitch {
  
  int total = 0;
  int[][] board = {{1,1,1,1,1}, {1,2,2,2,1}, {1,2,3,2,1}, {1,2,2,2,1}, {1,1,1,1,1}};
  String[][] boardWithP = {{"1", "1", "1", "1", "1"}, {"1", "2", "2", "2", "1"}, {"1", "2", "3", "2", "1"}, {"1", "2", "2", "2", "1"}, {"1", "1", "1", "1", "1"}};
  
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 0){
    int x = (int)(Math.random() * 5);
    int y = (int)(Math.random() * 5);
    
    if(boardWithP[x][y] != "P"){
      total += board[x][y];
      boardWithP[x][y] = "P";
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

So I keep getting a Syntax error

```
Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token
```

on line 8 and

```
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
```

on line to and I was wondering if anyone knew what the problem was. All my brackets seem to match up and there should be a semicolon on line 8 to my knowledge. Any suggestions?

Comment: Code goes inside methods, not directly inside a class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax error on token ";", "{" expected after this token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804598/syntax-error-on-token-expected-after-this-token)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't with the multidimensional arrays, which are fine. The issue is that you can't have code directly under a `class` - it needs to be in a method, constructor or initializer block. E.g.:

```
public class PennyPitch {
  
  int total = 0;
  int[][] board = {{1,1,1,1,1}, {1,2,2,2,1}, {1,2,3,2,1}, {1,2,2,2,1}, {1,1,1,1,1}};
  String[][] boardWithP = {{"1", "1", "1", "1", "1"}, {"1", "2", "2", "2", "1"}, {"1", "2", "3", "2", "1"}, {"1", "2", "2", "2", "1"}, {"1", "1", "1", "1", "1"}};
 
  public static void main(String[] args) { // Here!
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 0){
      int x = (int)(Math.random() * 5);
      int y = (int)(Math.random() * 5);
    
      if(boardWithP[x][y] != "P"){
        total += board[x][y];
        boardWithP[x][y] = "P";
        i++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, as a side note, you shouldn't use the `==` or `!=` operartors to compare strings, but use the `equals` method instead. See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/2422776) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code inside of a method (function)
Like this:

```java
public class PennyPitch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     int total = 0;
     int[][] board = {{1,1,1,1,1}, {1,2,2,2,1}, {1,2,3,2,1}, {1,2,2,2,1}, {1,1,1,1,1}};
     String[][] boardWithP = {{"1", "1", "1", "1", "1"}, {"1", "2", "2", "2", "1"}, {"1", "2", 
      "3", "2", "1"}, {"1", "2", "2", "2", "1"}, {"1", "1", "1", "1", "1"}};
  
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 0){
       int x = (int)(Math.random() * 5);
       int y = (int)(Math.random() * 5);
    
       if(boardWithP[x][y] != "P"){
          total += board[x][y];
         boardWithP[x][y] = "P";
         i++;
      }
    }
  } 
}
```